# Azure DevOps Calendar - is not allowing to use "Add days off"

Tags: azure, calendar, azure-devops

Since a few days the function "Add days off" in the Azure DevOps (VSTS) Team Calendar can no longer be used. However, the function could already be used. My account is authorized as project and team administrator. The popup can still be opened but without content. The button "OK" cannot be used either.

What I'm doing wrong?

The function can be found in the Azure DevOps portal under: **Boards / Calendar / Add days off**

[image]

via my browser console:

```
{stack: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'valueOf' of undef…endar/0.5.209/1513804816029/sdk/VSS.SDK.js:103:44", message: "Cannot read property 'valueOf' of undefined"}
message: "Cannot read property 'valueOf' of undefined"
stack: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'valueOf' of undefined↵    


at https://ms-devlabs.gallerycdn.vsassets.io/extensions/ms-devlabs/team-calendar/0.5.209/1513804816029/js/dialogs.js:902:70↵    
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)↵    
    at EditCapacityEventControl._getCurrentIteration (https://ms-devlabs.gallerycdn.vsassets.io/extensions/ms-devlabs/team-calendar/0.5.209/1513804816029/js/dialogs.js:899:31)↵    
    at https://ms-devlabs.gallerycdn.vsassets.io/extensions/ms-devlabs/team-calendar/0.5.209/1513804816029/js/dialogs.js:864:43↵    
    at XdmDeferred._wrapCallback (https://ms-devlabs.gallerycdn.vsassets.io/extensions/ms-devlabs/team-calendar/0.5.209/1513804816029/sdk/VSS.SDK.js:73:26)↵    
    at Array.<anonymous> (https://ms-devlabs.gallerycdn.vsassets.io/extensions/ms-devlabs/team-calendar/0.5.209/1513804816029/sdk/VSS.SDK.js:48:23)↵    
    at https://ms-devlabs.gallerycdn.vsassets.io/extensions/ms-devlabs/team-calendar/0.5.209/1513804816029/sdk/VSS.SDK.js:103:44"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Do you see an error in the browser console? did you try another browser? Does it happen only to you or to any user?

Comment: Affects multiple users. I have already tested this in several browsers with the same problem.

Comment: There is an open issue on GitHub for this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-team-calendar/issues/237

Comment: Thanks, I will watch this open issue. Here it still works with some projects.

Answer (score 1):

The reason Ok is grey, is because you are not a member of the team that the calendar relates too. If you look in the top left of calendar extension view, right beside the month you will see a drop down containing all the teams in your project. Your user account must be added to the team that is selected in order to add days off.

[image: Azure DevOps Calendar Team Selection Drop down]

Answer (score 0):

for me this thing sits under boards > sprints > capacity

[image]

ps. I dont have "calendars" under boards.

Comment: The "Team Calendar" it's an Azure DevOps extension, is not out of the box.

Comment: ok, i guess it means you can just remove it and use a native capability

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that. Yes it is an Azure DevOps extension.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have an active iteration running - that's the problem. Go to your Azure DevOps "Project Settings", under "Boards" you have "Project Configuration", there you can add a new iteration.

Or here is the direct link, but you have to replace your servername and projectname.

https://SERVERNAME/PROJECTNAME/_settings/work

After that you can go to calendar page and add day off.

Answer (score 0):

Click the "Days Off" in the right hand pane and add yourself to the team. This is required due to capacity planning integrations.

[image]

The other gotcha is that you can't create days off that span multiple iterations - e.g. extended breaks are not encouraged.   To workaround this - you must create multiple days off for each iteration you plan on being out.

Comment: Do you maybe know the answer for this one?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68096837/azure-pipeline-custom-task-with-an-unknown-number-of-inputs